# Get war module when running the parent maven project

Tags: maven

Is there a way to run a war module automatically when I run the parent project?
To make it clear, I did three separate maven project (db, core and presentation), then I made a parent project which include the 3 projects mentioned before.
I'd like to get the presentation module running when I run the parent project.

Also, I want to know if it's possible to save the hole work from the parent project to my git account.

```
     <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.project.xxxxxxx</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent-project</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <name>parent-project</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <targetJdk>1.7</targetJdk>
   </properties>

  <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <port>8080</port>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${targetJdk}</source>
                    <target>${targetJdk}</target>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <modules>
        <module>../project-db</module>
        <module>../project-core</module>
        <module>../project-presentation</module>
    </modules>


  <dependencies>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you provide the `pom.xml` of your parent project?

Comment: @Ria I've just added the pom file to my post

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the sub-project under  tag.
You may refer http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule-sect-simple-parent.html for example

Comment: sub-projects are all specified under <module> tag. My application runs without errors. All I need to know is how to get the presentation layer(a web page) when I run the parent project instead of running the presentation module.

Answer (score 0):

Your modules should be unter your parent in the file structure. Like

- parent-project

  - pom.xml
  - project-db

    - pom.xml
  - project-core

    - pom.xml
  - project-presentation

    - pom.xml

Then you have to change the parent pom:

```
<modules>
    <module>project-db</module>
    <module>project-core</module>
    <module>project-presentation</module>
</modules>
```

Comment: It's possible to do both like I did and like you mentioned above, my solution work out perfectly.The question still remaining how to run the presentation project directly when I run the parent project.

Comment: Sorry, this was my fault. I didn't read the question carefully. The presentation module is a war, right? Do you want to tun it on tomcat, jetty or another server?

Comment: Np. The presentation module is a war and when I run it directly it works. I am running my project on tomcat7